# Removing duplicates from SQL Join

Tags: sql, join

The following is a hypothetical situation this which is close to my real problem. `Table1`

```
recid   firstname    lastname   company
1       A             B          AAA
2       D             E          DEF
3       G             H          IJK
4       A             B          ABC
```

I have a table2 that looks like this

```
recid   firstname    lastname   company
10      A             B          ABC
20      D             E          DEF
30      M             D          DIM
40      A             B          CCC
```

Now if I join the table on `recid`, it will give `0` results, there will be no duplicates because `recid` is unique. But if I join on `firstname` and `lastname` columns, which are not unique and there are duplicates, I get duplicates on inner join. The more columns I add on join, the worse it becomes (more duplicates are created).

In the above simple situation, how can I remove duplicates in the following query? I want to compare `firstname` and `lastname`, if they match, I return `firstname`, `lastname` and `recid` from `table2`

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM
(SELECT recid, first, last FROM table1) a
INNER JOIN
(SELECT recid, first,last FROM table2) b
ON a.first = b.first
```

---

The script is here if anyone wants to play with it in future

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (recid INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, first varchar(20), last varchar(20), company varchar(20))
CREATE TABLE table2 (recid INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, first varchar(20), last varchar(20), company varchar(20))

INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(1,'A','B','ABC')
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(2,'D','E','DEF')
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(3,'M','N','MNO')
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(4,'A','B','ABC')

INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES(10,'A','B','ABC')
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES(20,'D','E','DEF')
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES(30,'Q','R','QRS')
INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES(40,'A','B','ABC')
```

Comment: Do you need the recid back - if not, removing it from your query would fix your issue.

Comment: yes, otherwise I have done the rest.

Comment: You need to decide on logic for your non-dupe rows.  CompanyId and RecId are different for your dupes.  Which of these do you want to keep>

Comment: @Savage: So, in the above example, your result shoulbe the three rows with `recid: 10,20,40` ?

Comment: @Savage Garden: have you tried my query?

Comment: In my original query, I am using two sub queries because both queries are run on the same table with different where clauses. If firstname and lastname matches in the two subequeries, i return the names + recid + one other field.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You don't want to do a join per se, you're merely testing for existence/set inclusion.

I don't know what current flavor of SQL you're coding in, but this should work.

```
SELECT MAX(recid), firstname, lastname 
FROM table2 T2
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE firstname = T2.firstame AND lastname = T2.lastname)
GROUP BY lastname, firstname
```

If you want to implement as a join, leaving the code largely the same:

i.e.

```
SELECT max(t2.recid), t2.firstame, t2.lastname 
FROM Table2 T2 
INNER JOIN Table1 T1 
    ON T2.firstname = t1.firstname and t2.lastname = t1.lastname
GROUP BY t2.firstname, t2.lastname
```

Depending on the DBMS, an inner join may be implemented differently to an Exists (semi-join vs join) but the optimizer can sometimes figure it out anyway and chose the correct operator regardless of which way you write it.

Comment: His sample code had a select * from both datasets but his description stated "I want to compare firstname and lastname, if they match, I return firstname, lastname and recid *from table2*"

Comment: this is it. I guess I dont need join, but can someone explain it in join as well if it is possible.

Comment: His sample code using `SELECT DISTINCT *` from an `INNER JOIN`ed result set indicates pretty clearly he wants data from both tables.  If I'm wrong and he clarifies I will happily remove the DV.

Comment: In my case it works without `MAX(recid)` (the original query). Second query does not result in the same. Thanks though.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT t2.recid, t2.first, t2.last 
FROM  table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.first = t2.first AND t1.last = t2.last
GROUP BY t2.recid, t2.first, t2.last
```

**EDIT: Added picture**

[image]

Comment: I tried similar to my original query but did not work for some reason thanks.

Comment: @Savage Garden: you mean query I've provided not working? Does image represents wrong result set?

Comment: It does work. The problem is I only want to keep the recid unique. The rest can be duplicate. Like I dont want group by t2.first and t2.last. But using group by, you have to use it.

Answer (score 1):

There are some situations when you have to do grouping in a subquery

```sql
SELECT distinct b.recid, b.first, b.last 
FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(recid) as recid, first, last 
  FROM table2
  GROUP BY first, last
) b
ON a.first = b.first AND a.last = b.last
```