# Insert statement with no joins results in duplicates where no duplicates existed previously?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having an issue with some SQL that is resulting in results that I wouldn't expect. I am storing information from a variety of tables in another table which is used as part of a search page on a website. All of the page data for each page, along with data from other elements on other pages (like calendars, etc) is referenced in a table called `pageContentCache`. This table has normally has an index against created with the following:

```
alter table pageContentCache add
    constraint [IX_pageContentCache] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
        [objectId]
    )
```

For some reason that to me would appear to be a duplicate `objectId`, an issue has started occurring with one instance of this software, resulting in the following error:

> Msg 1505, Level 16, State 1 Procedure sp_rebuildPageContentCache, Line 50
>
> The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object name 'dbo.pageContentCache' and the index name 'IX_pageContentCache'. The duplicate key value is (21912).

So, to debug the issue, I had got the procedure to load all of the data it was going to input into the `pageContentCache` table into a temporary table, `#contentcache`, first, so I could have a look through it.

**This is where I'm starting to get a little confused...**

Once the data has been inserted into `#contentcache` (which has two columns, `objectId` and `content`), I can run the following SQL statement and it will return nothing:

```
select objectId, count(objectId) from #contentcache
group by objectId having count(objectId) > 1
```

This returns *no records*. If I then run the following SQL:

```
insert into pageContentCache (objectId, contentData)
    select objectId, content
    from #contentcache
```

This inserts all of the data from `#contentcache` into `pageContentCache` as you'd expect. However, if I then run the following SQL, it returns duplicates:

```
select objectId, count(objectId) from pageContentCache
group by objectId having count(objectId) > 1
```

This then returns duplicates:

```
objectId     (no column name)
21912        2
```

There are no triggers or anything like that associated with this table and the insert statement is merely copying the data from one table to another, so... where is this duplicate coming from?

Comment: Is `pageContentCache` empty before you're inserting the data? You've checked that your temp table has no duplicates, but that doesn't guarantee you won't be inserting duplicates into the regular table.

Comment: Yes, I've even deleted the table and recreated it as part of my testing. The `pageContentCache` table has 0 records in it before I do my insert. The full procedure that is run when manually rebuilding the search cache also drops the table and re-creates it as the first step of the process, so the possibility of there ever being duplicates *before* I ever arrived on the scene to investigate the issue would have been non-existent as well.

Comment: What is the datatype of `objectId` column in both `#contentcache` table and in `pageContentCache` table?

Comment: What type is `objectId` in # table? Floating point?

Comment: In both instances (`#contentcache` and `pageContentCache`) `objectId` is `INT NOT NULL` and `contentData` (`content` in `#contentcache`) is `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

Comment: Check the total number of rows in the #contentcache and in the pageContentCache tables. Do they match?

Comment: No - `pageContentCache` after the insert has 22778 rows with one row duplicated while `#contentcache` has 22777 records with no duplicates

Comment: @Flyk - So any concurrent processes that insert to that table?

Comment: @MartinSmith only if IIS was running (which it isn't) as it would be trying to update the contents of the search cache. Since IIS is disabled this isn't the case. (Also, MSSQL activity monitor shows me as the only user connected at the moment)

Comment: You've double checked you haven't left a rogue single insert statement lying around in your script?

Comment: 100% sure, there are no inserts doing anything other than bulk inserting the contents of one table to another. The data that makes it into the `#contentcache` table originates from another stored proc so my current script only has a single uncommented insert statement in it and everything else is commented out.

Comment: Can you share the DDL of the table pageContentCache?

Comment: I'm using the following create statements: `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[pageContentCache]( objectId INT NOT NULL, contentData NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL );` and `CREATE TABLE #contentcache( objectId INT NOT NULL, content NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL)`

Comment: Can you do something like that, just to be sure:
<code>select count(1) from pageContentCache  
insert into pageContentCache (objectId, contentData)  
select objectId, content
  from #contentcache
select count(1) from pageContentCache
<code>

Comment: Can you replicate this on a seperate database?

Comment: `select * from #contentcache where objectId = 21912` gives what?

Comment: @TTeeple I'm transferring the customer's data over to me now so I can test it with their data on a separate server, going to take some time though...

Comment: `two identical rows, like it was inserted twice` Huh? And still the select count shows no duplicates?

Comment: Yes- the source table has no duplicates and the insert contained no joins

Comment: @arvo a single row with an objectid of 21912

Comment: @dmitry fixed my comment, misread the table name since i have already answered *that* question in my question body.

Comment: Can you try `select count(1) from pageContentCache; insert into pageContentCache (objectId, contentData) select objectId, content from #contentcache; select count(1) from pageContentCache`?

Comment: @DmitryS since the contents of pageContentCache is removed (since the table is dropped and recreated before anything is inserted into it) your SQL returns 0 and *some number of rows* which is equal to count() from #contentcache + 1 - I'm thinking this might have something to do with SQL's caching since the issue stopped happening without any changes being made to the SQL being run (ie: the SQL seems to now be working as expected?) - now this is a bit of an academic discussion until it happens again (since this has happened multiple times before). Since we drop and recreate the table before...

Comment: ...adding anything to it, `pageContentCache` will always be empty before we start inserting to it. The reason I'm looking at this error is because one of our automated processes (which runs the original version of this stored procedure, that simply inserts straight into `pageContentCache` without the temporary table in between) was failing with a duplicate key error when trying to create the index. The stored procedure (and the SQL that I derived from it) does the following: drop table pageContentCache, exec a stored proc that returns unique (identity) element IDs into pageContentCache...

Comment: ...create indexes against pageContentCache (which is where the error occurs, because a duplicate "appears" that doesn't exist, since all of the objectIds are identity fields from another single table responsible for storing the data stored in each of these elements - my alteration was to investigate the issue in which I created a temporary table so I could check and remove duplicates before inserting into pageContentCache, under the assumption that duplicates were appearing as a result of values returned from the stored procedure that I can't edit (since it's encrypted)

Comment: There seems to be a lot of background here (specific to the application you're running) that would render it a waste of time for a forum like this to respond to.  If you think the cache issue has anything to do with it, then that would be a question for Microsoft support, not Stack.

Comment: @cartbeforehorse I asked here for a sanity check before escalating it further. I had hoped it was a case of me being stupid rather than it being something outside of my control.

Comment: @Flyk Consider yourself sanity-checked. :-)  Especially if it works sometimes, and not others.

Comment: @Flyk Re "issue stopped happening without any changes" - have you checked your database against corruption? `dbcc checkdb` I mean. I would check RAM and disk subsystem either, although problems with hardware should have caused many more (and unrepeatable) errors.

Comment: This is may be an indexing or cache issue.

[The link may help you][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084577/removing-duplicates-from-sql-join

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
insert into pageContentCache (objectId, contentData)
    select distinct objectId, content
    from #contentcache
```

Can't see why you would have duplicates since, as you mentioned, there are no joins in your select statement.  Anyways, my guess is that the distinct keyword will ensure that the duplicates are eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a SQL Server database error I have seen before. You may want to patch the latest service pack and retry.

Comment: Please show a relevant KB article discussing this issue. SQL Server inserting phantom rows randomly would be a pretty crucial error. There's probably a perfectly mundane explanation that we can't determine without access to the system.

Answer (score -1):

I am not so sure that this statement does what you think it does:

```
select objectId, count(objectId) from #contentcache
group by objectId having count(objectId) > 1
```

Can you try this instead:

```
WITH SUBQUERY AS
( select 
COUNT(objectId) OVER (PARTITION BY objectId) AS CNT_OBJECT_IDS,
objectId
FROM #contentcache)
SELECT * FROM SUBQUERY WHERE CNT_OBJECT_IDS > 1
```

See if this gets you any rows back.

Also, I've never worked with clusters before and I am wondering if they do some additional things that we are not aware of. Can you try just saying

```
PRIMARY KEY
```

instead of

```
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

in your constraint definition and see if that affects your problem at all?

Comment: Whether or not the index is clustered has nothing to do with the duplicate key, it's just the underlying data structure.  Either way, specifying PRIMARY KEY without the CLUSTERED or NONCLUSTERED key word results in a clustered index as long as the table doesn't already have one, so changing the syntax isn't going to affect the behavior in any way.