# MYSQL query result with inner join

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Below query is working but it gives me same data multiple times....
suggest me to slove this

```
"SELECT 
     cp.projectID,cp.projectName,cp.clientID,
     pv.vendorID,
     cv.vendorName,
     c.clientName,
     vp.productName,
     pp.sku
FROM clientProjects AS cp 
    INNER JOIN clients AS c ON c.clientID = cp.clientID
    INNER JOIN projectVendors AS pv ON cp.projectID = pv.projectID
    INNER JOIN clientVendors AS cv ON cv.vendorID = pv.vendorID
    INNER JOIN projectProducts AS pp ON cp.projectID = pp.projectID 
    INNER JOIN projectMaintenance AS pm ON cp.projectID = pm.projectID
    INNER JOIN vendorProducts AS vp ON pp.sku = vp.sku
    INNER JOIN projectFiles AS pf ON cp.projectID = pf.projectID
WHERE cp.projectName LIKE '".$projectName."' OR c.clientName LIKE '".$projectName."' OR pp.sku LIKE '".$projectName."' OR pm.sku LIKE '".$projectName."' "
```

Comment: try group by keyword

Comment: Use distinct or group by to avoid redundancy.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084577/removing-duplicates-from-sql-join

Comment: Tables without a column in the select list do not need to be joined. If just existence of a row is required, add EXISTS sub-query to WHERE clause,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try DISTINCT:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cp.projectID,
                cp.projectName,
                cp.clientID, 
                pv.vendorID, 
                cv.vendorName, 
                c.clientName, 
                vp.productName, 
                pp.sku
FROM clientProjects AS cp 
INNER JOIN clients AS c ON c.clientID = cp.clientID
INNER JOIN projectVendors AS pv ON cp.projectID = pv.projectID
INNER JOIN clientVendors AS cv ON cv.vendorID = pv.vendorID
INNER JOIN projectProducts AS pp ON cp.projectID = pp.projectID 
INNER JOIN projectMaintenance AS pm ON cp.projectID = pm.projectID
INNER JOIN vendorProducts AS vp ON pp.sku = vp.sku
INNER JOIN projectFiles AS pf ON cp.projectID = pf.projectID
WHERE cp.projectName LIKE '".$projectName."' OR 
      c.clientName LIKE '".$projectName."' OR 
      pp.sku LIKE '".$projectName."' OR 
      pm.sku LIKE '".$projectName."' "
```